# Is it possible to make the results of dividing corresponding elements in two arrays into one output array a one-liner?

Tags: python, for-loop

I wish to make a one-line for loop for array. The for loop look like this:

```
for i in range(0, len(array)):
       temp_array[i] = array[i]/product[i]
```

I tried

with `temp_array[i] = array[i]/product[i] for i in range(0, len(array)` It says there is a wrong syntax.

is it possible or I can't make one-line for loops for arrays?

Comment: No. Doesn't the code look cleaner with one-liners? I always thought so. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: Code should be written for clarity, not terseness. Making something "cleaner" but harder-to-read is a false economy.

Comment: (...which is part of why we kicked code golf questions out of Stack Overflow to [codegolf.se], and clarified Stack Overflow's rules such that only _practical_ questions are permitted here)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Can list comprehensions, especially uncomplicated ones like the one in this instance be considered as terse? If they were, I suspect they would not be part of the language, and/or the recommendation would be to not use them at all. In any event, the problem the OP faced was a simple syntax one (missing brackets) and he was wondering whether there was syntax that would allow what he wanted. Fair learning question, irrespective of the clarity vs terseness argument, or so I thought.

Comment: @Philippe, ...sorry? "Terse" isn't _innately_ a bad thing; it's only a bad thing when it's at conflict with clarity. Your answer is fine; I have a problem with the class of question, however, because often we get OPs insisting on one-liners even even for code that _isn't_ amenable to simple, clear answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are after:

```
temp_array = [array[i] / product[i] for i in range(len(array))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension with zip to process both lists at the same time, for example:

```
array = [2, 4]
products = [8, 16]

temp_array = [ 
    a/p for a, p in zip(array, products) 
]

print(temp_array)
>>> [0.25, 0.25]
```